# Writing less data using fwrite as compared to console display

Tags: c

[image]

I am having issue in writing the output data in output file.

With print message I can see the outputs on console but when I am trying with hexdump with outfile.y file I can see that output at some memory index is zeros.

NOTE: I am expecting the division result is `uint64_t` format only .

System: `Linux`

Tool: `Eclipse`

command: `hexdump outfile.y`

**Can any one suggest me whether I am using fwrite correctly or do I need to do some changes there in fwrite .**

**EDITED:** Updated question with screen shot which shows zero data from `00000040` memory address to  `00000070`
As per the console printf output I can print output values using printf on colsole output but the same is not visible in given files from `00000050` to `00000060`(showing zeros).

This is my C code .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define TEST_RUNS 200
#define NUM_INPUT_VALUES 128

#define RANDINT_VAL()   (rand() ^ rand() <<1 )

typedef struct {
    uint64_t s0;
} ulong1;

struct data_inres_t {
    ulong1 i[NUM_INPUT_VALUES];
};

struct data_outres_t {
    ulong1 val[NUM_INPUT_VALUES];
};

int main()
{
    uint64_t buf_in0_s0;
    uint64_t buf_in1_s0;

    uint64_t buf_out0_s0;

    // Output test data
    ulong1 res0;

    struct data_inres_t buf_in0;
    struct data_inres_t buf_in1 ;

    struct data_outres_t buf_out0 ;


    /* prepare dump text file, contains all input / output / reference data */
    FILE* f0_out = fopen("outfile.y", "wb"); //Updated with wb after suggestion but not helped in solving this issue
    if (NULL == f0_out) {
        printf("HOST:ERROR in creating output file %s\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < TEST_RUNS; j++) {
        printf("loop: %d\n", j);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_INPUT_VALUES; i++) {
            //Random generated input0
            buf_in0.i[i].s0 = (uint64_t)(RANDINT_VAL() >> (rand() %31)); 
            //Random generated input1
            buf_in1.i[i].s0 = (uint64_t)(RANDINT_VAL() >> (rand() %16));
            //Condition to avoid div by zero cases and zero cases
            if(buf_in0.i[i].s0 == 0) buf_in0.i[i].s0 = MAX_INT;
            if(buf_in1.i[i].s0 == 0) buf_in1.i[i].s0 = MAX_INT;

            buf_in0_s0 = (uint64_t)(buf_in0.i[i].s0);
            buf_in1_s0 = (uint64_t)(buf_in1.i[i].s0);

            buf_out0_s0 = (uint64_t)(buf_in0_s0 / buf_in1_s0);

            buf_out0.val[i].s0 = buf_out0_s0;

        }

        fwrite(&buf_out0, NUM_INPUT_VALUES * sizeof(ulong1), 1, f0_out);

        printf("HOST:Generated Output\n");
    }

    fclose(f0_out);

    printf("Done !!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The division result may be zero. Did you check values in `buf_in0` and `buf_in1`?

Comment: May be I will edit my code to show how I am skiping div by zero condition .

Comment: A 64-bit integer could be 19 digits written as text to console, but is only 8 bytes written to binary file.

Comment: @WeatherVane, when I printed my results in hex : `Input0= 1d7e` and  `Input1= 1d7e`  ....output on console is : 0x1 ..But in outfile.y with hexdump I can see only zeros ..Do I need to change fwrite for that ?

Comment: It still outputs up to twice the data to console. I am looking at the question title, and a wall of code with baredly distinguishable variable names.

Comment: Also, if this is MSVC you *must* specify binary with `"wb"`

Comment: You should open the file in binary mode so you don't have any unexpected line ending conversion on platforms where that applies.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I have updated now the code for wb mode .I am working on linux and using hexdump to see the file . Is there any other tool you want to suggest me for outfile.y ..Update: No luck .Still can see the same output like above.

Comment: System:` Linux` ..Tool: `Eclipse` ... command: `hexdump outfile.y`